# Unable to Link MS Visio shape to specific MS Word document page (other than the 1st page)

Tags: hyperlink, microsoft-word-2016, microsoft-visio-2016

I am using MS Office 2016 and Visio Professional.  I created a process flow chart with 20+ shapes. I am now trying to create hyperlinks in Visio that will open to a specific page or paragraph in MS Word (other than the first page of the document). Currently, I am only able to get it linked to the first page despite creating bookmarks in the Word document as well. Any input is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't reproduce the issue with my Office 2016 and Visio Professional 2016:

[image]

Do you use "#" to link bookmark and document path? You can [repair your Office and Visio](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/repair-an-office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b) to have a check.